# WordPress .htaccess: have site in subdomain resolve to TLD/root domain too

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a site that currently sits on `example.com/uk/` - that's the URL, and it physically lives in that location (there is also another WP installation in the root on `example.com/`). I now need `example.co.uk` to resolve to the site that lives in `example.com/uk/`. The new URL needs to be up & working for visitors ASAP, but there are dozens of services integrated with the 'old' URL which can't all be switched instantly, hence the need to have both URLs active at once.

I've managed to get all of this working with a CNAME in the DNS and edits in the `wp-config.php` to accept both the incoming `.com/uk` & `.co.uk`, and it works for the home page; however if I go any deeper on the `.co.uk`, I get server error.

I've narrowed this down to the `.htaccess` file, but I can't get it work as expected for both domains. The original `.htaccess` looked like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /uk/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /uk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My latest attempt looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/uk/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /uk/
RewriteRule . /uk/index.php [L]
```

...but none of the scripts or CSS load (I think they end up in an infinite loop). I suspect part of the issue is the `RewriteBase`, but that doesn't seem to respond to `RewriteCond`s.

TL;DR I need a WP website to work on both a root URL and a subdirectory URL, but I can't figure out the `.htaccess` rules to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Apache 2.4+, this can be done with an `<If/Else>` conditional in the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.co.uk'">
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </If>

    <ElseIf "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
        RewriteBase /uk/
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /uk/index.php [L]
    </ElseIf>
</IfModule>
```

Note that your `wp-config.php` file also needs to be able to accept & resolve the site to the incoming domain:

```
$allowableDomains = array(
    'example.co.uk',
    'example.com/uk',
);

define('DOMAIN_ARRAY', $allowableDomains);

function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}

#   The protocol should be whatever your site is using:

$protocol = 'https://';
$refHost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (in_arrayi($refHost, $allowableDomains)) {
    $siteURL = $protocol . $refHost;
} else {
    $siteURL = $protocol . $allowableDomains[0];
}

define('WP_SITEURL', $siteURL);
define('WP_HOME', $siteURL);
```

This will allow any incoming domain, but default to `.co.uk` if you're pointing any other domains that aren't in the `$allowableDomains` array.